# Unir variable mas palabra php mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

Hola a todos tengo una duda, como unir una palabra + una variabla en un query php mysql.

```
$Sql_Query = "select * from usuario where user_email = '$email' and user_password = '$password' ";
```

Quiero agregarle a la palabra usuario una variable que quede
usuario'$variable'

Para que juntes formen una sola palabra de quede por ejemplo 
 usuario5566   (palabra usuario + la variable)

y pueda hacer la consulta

```
select * from usuario5566 where ............
```

Gracias y saludos

Comment: ya intentaste `$usuario = 'usuario5566' //o el valor que necesitas ` y `$Sql_Query = "select * from '$usuario' where user_email = '$email' and user_password = '$password' ";` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$tabla = 5566;
$query = "select * from usuario$tabla where user_email = '$email' and user_password = '$password' ";
```

Solo tienes que agregar la variable donde la necesites, siempre y cuando la cadena esté delimitada por comillas dobles, como es tu caso.